# How to display specific labels on igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a very large igraph but when I plot, I want that just specific labels appear. Those labels are saved in different dfs (`activator` and `receptor`).
I tried with:

```
nodes <- data.frame(symbol = LETTERS[1:7])
edges <- data.frame(from=c("B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "G"),
                    to = c("A", "B", "A", "E", "B", "A", "F", "F"))

activator <- c('A')
receptor <- c('E', 'F', 'G')

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=TRUE, vertices=nodes)
print(g, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.label1 = ifelse(V(g)$name %in% c(activator, receptor), V(g)$name, NA))
```

But it is not working. Any comments?

Comment: Hi, could you add a reproducible example to copy and paste in R? It's going to help to detect the error.

Comment: Hi, I just added the example.

Comment: If an edge has a node in `c(activator, receptor)`, and a node out `c(activator, receptor )` do you want it or not?

Comment: I just want to display the names of `activator` and `receptor` in the plot.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it. It _almost_ worked. The only problem was in your plot you have `vertex.label1 = ifelse ...` I changed it to `vertex.label = ifelse ...`    (remove the 1) and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @G5W so true!! I did not notice that mistake. Thank you so much!! Now it works.